# Construct upper block diagonal matrix from block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I want to construct a matrix A such that:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B\\
C & D\\
\end{pmatrix} * A = \begin{pmatrix}
* & *\\
0 & *\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

where B, C, D $\in K^{n\times n}$.

Comment: try with $n=1$, maybe you`ll find some good idea..

Comment: I could do n Row-switching transformations, I can not really think of the matrix, but that brings me at least a bit further in calculation the determinant of the left matrix.

Comment: write also $A$ divided in 4 parts, and try to find a good one

Comment: Multiplying with \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} works when you multiply from the left (switches first row with second one)